# Confuse: Domain Model vs Entity/@Transcient vs EntityWrapper

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

I have a 3 tier design for my web application

Data Layer -> Service Layer -> Presentation

My web application uses these framework
1) Spring MVC
2) Spring
3) Hibernate (Spring Repository)

### Problem/Dilemma Statement

Lets say I have PersonEntity(Hibernate - Data Layer)

It have the following attributes that doesn't comes from the database)

- age, which is calculated from Date of Birth(assume this is a complex
  calculation that you can't do it on view with .js)
- status indicator that is map to a look-up dictionary (ie S - Single,
  M - Married - D - Divorced)
- Some other business related attributes

When this Entity get push to the service and view layer. How should I build all this business logic?

So to manage this I have 3 approaches

1. Use Entity with @Transient and populate those transient attribute
   using an    Assembler/Factory class
2. Create a EntityWrapper

   ```
   public class PersonWrapper {

   private Person person;

   private int age;
   ```
3. Have a PersonModel aka POJO and populate database values and other attributes
       in a builder class

### Question

Assuming I will be using the full fledged of functions like lazy loading, there are security concerns and etc. 
I will be applying the same approach even for entity that doesn't have any special attributes (ie my DomainModelBuilder might just be building a PersonModel by setting each values again)

1. Which of the above is a better approach?
2. Is there a more correct approach?
3. What is the architecture term for my approach? ie Domain Driver Design and etc
4. Any other way to approach my issue?

I personally prefer 3rd approach because is more clean but some of the developers are complaining that they are doing extra work and extra processing because they are rebuilding models that are exactly like the entity.
That is why I am thinking the 2 approach is better because they don't have to do extra processing and still able to separate aggregate values

Comment: The Domain Driven Design approach to this would be to have a Domain layer between Data and Service, and make Person a persistence-ignorant Domain entity with all needed properties (age, status, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The site's css/js doesn't work, so the answer maybe unformatted.

I prefer the second solution. But I use a variation, for example

```
public class PersonDetailViewAdapter {
    private Person person
    private PersonStatusDict personStatusDict;

    public PersonDetailViewAdapter(Person person, PersonStatusDict personStatusDict) {
         this.person = person;
         this.personStatusDict = personStatusDict;
    }

    public String getAge() {//you don't have to use a field
        return person.getAge()//age calculation seems to be a domain logic
    } 

    public String getStatusName() {
        return personStatusDict.translate(person.getStatus());
    }
}
```

But this really depends on the complexity of your view. It's quite boring to write such a wrapper if the view requirment is straightfoward, then you would end up with a wrapper with every method just delegating to the entity wrapped(Assume, the status dict is quite simple and don't need external dependence such as look up from datasource, then Person.getStatusName() is more convenient). In this case, I would pick the first solution.

Below is an example of my view adapter:

```
public class AirTicketDetailViewAdapter {

private AirTicket ticket;

public AirTicketDetailViewAdapter(AirTicket ticket) {
    this.ticket = ticket;
}

public String getId() {
    return ticket.getId();//avoid train wreck code
}

public String getNumber() {
            //avoid dispaly null, this attribute is empty if not ticketed
    return ObjectUtils.nullSafeTrim(ticket.getNumber());
}

public String getRemark() {
    return ObjectUtils.nullSafeTrim(ticket.getRemark());
}

public String getTraveler() {
    AirTraveler traveler = ticket.getTraveler();
    String fullName = traveler.passengerType().name() + Constants.SPACE
            + traveler.fullName();
    if (traveler.isInfant()) {
        fullName += Constants.SPACE + "(" + traveler.getCarriedBy() + ")";
    }
    return fullName;
}

public String getDocumentNumber() {
    AirTraveler traveler = ticket.getTraveler();
    if (traveler.isAdult()) {
        return traveler.getDocument().getNumber();
    } else if (traveler.isChild() || traveler.isInfant()) {
        return DateUtils.format(traveler.getDocument().getDateOfBirth(),
                Constants.DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN);
    } else {
        return PassengerType.UNKNOWN.name();
    }
}

public String getDocumentType() {
    return ticket.getTraveler().getDocument().type().name();
}

public String getStatusName() {
    return ticket.status().name();
}

public String getTotalAmount() {
    Money totalAmount = ticket.getTotalAmount();
    return totalAmount.getCurrencySymbol() + totalAmount.getAmount();
}
```

}

The View Adapter above aimed to

1. Avoid train wreck code on jsp(harder to refact on jsp, the model was not stable at that time)
2. Avoid if/else jsplet code on jsp. We developed acceptance tests against on api layer(It is more expensive to make the test interact with ui directly), so jsps weren't covered in any automated tests. however, we wrote unit tests(cheaper) for these ViewAdapters.

The disadvantage I ever heard is

1. The second solution introduce subtle inconsistency if someone update the entity after it is passed to the ViewAdapter(It's a .net related post, I cannot find it now)
2. There is potential session closed exception if you want to access lazy-loading property if you adopt delegate getAge() strategy. This depends on you persistence infrastructure, it was ok when we used iBATIS, failed when we switched to Hibernate without extra dettach.

Last but not least, the decision should be made based on your project and your team. I don't think there is an one-size-fits-all solution.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: try to +1 for effort but can't

Comment: i think there is an issue when you put BL in your get/set . when jsp. renders.. it will call it multiple times and end up wasting a lot of process time.

Comment: @user4127 Sorry, I don't get it. Could you elaborate it? BL means business logic? What is the it in "call it muptiple times", getAge() in my example? And why it will be called mupltiple times?

Comment: I just implemented this today, is quite good as I don't have to do any code change.. but I notice there is more manual coding to get out the helper methods. (ie. getId() return obj.getId(); is there a eclipse function to extract out those required?

Comment: Hmm...Maybe you should consider whether to take this solution when you find plethora of simple delegate methods(ie. getId() return obj.getId();), take transient entity solution instead or Use some mapper tools(like http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) to populate your view object if you insist decouple domain model from ui.

Comment: Transient Method is absolutely no-no because it will mix the Domain and entity.